# {Flex: 1} not working with relative positioning

Tags: react-native

I want the second `View` to be relatively positioned at -50 below the first `View`, but the second `View` does not extend completely at the bottom.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export const OverlayStorybook = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <Text>OverlayStorybook</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', top: 0}} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export const OverlayStorybook = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <Text>OverlayStorybook</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', top: -50}} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

[image]

You can see at the bottom there are 50 pixels that are white.

Comment: Have you tried: `<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', top: -50, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0}} />`?

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi Same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found the answer to my question by myself. Just needed to wrap the second `View` inside a `View` and put position `absolute`.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export const OverlayStorybook = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <Text>OverlayStorybook</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            position: 'absolute',
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            top: -50,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippets

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1, position: "relative" }}>
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              backgroundColor: "red",
              position: "absolute",
              top: 0,
              zIndex: 1,
              width: "100%"
            }}
          >
            <Text>OverlayStorybook</Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              border: "1px solid green",
              marginTop: 50,
              zIndex: 2
            }}
          />
        </View>
```

Comment: Your second solution is React.js not React native.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option I figured out: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/full-flex

So removing flex and putting absolute positioning, then adding 50 (instead of subtracting it). Of course that "50" depends on the position you want to fit it in. So basically it's error prone if height of header element is changed.

```
<View style={{position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'rgba(32, 32, 128, 0.8)', top: 50, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}} />
</View>
```